# CakePHP 3.x + CRUD + JWT with custom Authentication

Tags: cakephp, authentication, crud, cakephp-3.0, jwt

I am having a problem with hooking up FriendsOfCake CRUD + JWT with my custom authentication method (e.g. not using the built in Cake3 PasswordHasher as much as I would like to).

I followed http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/ as much as possible, but my setup differs in that I will never be registering a user through the API, I will only need to generate a token against the username and password.

I can get the token to be generated using my function below (with some caveats)

But I have two problems:

1) What do I do with the Token? It doesn't seem to be added to the Session, how do I have this included in each request after the token is issued?

2) According to the bravo-kernel article the token method should be added to UsersController, however when I do this I get

```
"message": "Action \"token\" has not been mapped",
```

And then if I map it to a CRUD method such as Add then it works but it also creates a blank row in my Users table which is really not what I want.

Token Method is:

```
public function token()
{
    if($this->request->is('post')) {


        //returns $user object or false
        $query = $this->Users->_checkUser($this->request->query);

        if ($query) {
            $this->set('data', [
                'id' => $query->id,
                'token' => $token = \JWT::encode(
                    [
                        'id' => $query->id,
                        'exp' => time() + 604800
                    ],
                    Security::salt())
            ]);

            $this->Crud->action()->config('serialize.data', 'data');


        } else {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
    return $this->Crud->execute();
}
```

I'm struggling to find any examples other than the link above so any hints as to where I'm going wrong are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will only need to generate a token against the username and password.

So your `token()` method needs to verify the credentials and if valid return a token in response. The `token()` method in the tutorial you have linked does exactly that.

> 1) What do I do with the Token? It doesn't seem to be added to the Session, how do I have this included in each request after the token is issued?

Token based authentication are stateless, so session is not used and the client is supposed to save the token for passing in all requests. For e.g. you can use HTML5's `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to save the token.

> however when I do this I get `"message": "Action \"token\" has not been mapped"`

Add additional route for the `token()` method as shown [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#mapping-additional-resource-routes).

Comment: Got it - In the end I just disabled CRUD for that action and had JSONView return the json for it so it wasn't creating the table row.
The route thing was what was missing - thanks :)